# Solve $\int_{\frac{-π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{4}} \frac{(\sec^6 x - \tan^6 x)}{(a ^ x + 1) \cos^2 x} dx , (a > 0)$

Tags: calculus

This integral involves secant ($\sec(x)$) and tangent ($\tan(x)$) functions with even powers, and a cosine squared ($\cos^2(x)$) term in the denominator. I try to  solve it using a combination of trigonometric identities and a strategic substitution.

Here's how i approach it:

Reduce $\sec^6(x) $ and $\tan^6(x)$:

We can use the identity $$\sec^2(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x)$$ to rewrite $\sec^6(x)$.

$$\sec^6(x) = (\sec^2(x))^3 = (1 + \tan^2(x))^3$$

Similarly, we can rewrite $\tan^6(x)$ using the same identity.

$$\tan^6(x) = (\tan^2(x))^3$$

Substitute with a new variable:

Let's introduce a new variable, say $u = \tan(x)$. This substitution allows us to express $\sec(x)$ in terms of $u$ using the identity $$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \sqrt{1 + \tan^2(x)} = \sqrt{1 + u^2}$$

Rewrite the integral with the new variable:

Substitute $\sec(x)$ and $\tan(x)$ with their expressions in terms of $u$ and rewrite the differential term $dx$ using $$du = \sec^2(x) dx$$.

The integral becomes:

$$\int_{\frac{-π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{4}}\frac{(- (1 + u^2))^3 - u^6) }{ (a^x + 1) \cos^2(x) } dx$$

$$\int_{\frac{-π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{4}}\frac{(- (1 + u^2))^3 - u^6}{(a^x + 1) (\frac{1}{1 + u^2})} du$$

Comment: Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Use $\sec^6 x - \tan^6 x= 1 + 3 \sec^2 x \tan^2 x$

Answer (score 0):

First, we must get rid of the annoying $a^x+1$ term. Substitute $-x \rightarrow x$ in the original equation. You get

\begin{align}
 I = \int_{\frac{-π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{4}} \frac{(\sec^6 x - \tan^6 x)}{(a ^ {-x} + 1) \cos^2 x} dx 
\end{align}
Add this to the original integral to get
\begin{align}
 2I &= \int_{\frac{-π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{4}} \frac{(\sec^6 x - \tan^6 x)}{ \cos^2 x}\left( \frac{1}{a ^ {x} + 1} + \frac{1}{a ^ {-x} + 1} \right) dx \\
&= \int_{\frac{-π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{4}} \frac{(\sec^6 x - \tan^6 x)}{ \cos^2 x} dx
\end{align}
Now, apply the change of variable $u = \tan(x)$ to above to reach
\begin{align}
 2I &= \int_{-1}^{1} \left((1+u^2)^3 - u^6\right) du
\end{align}
The rest is easy. The final answer is $I = 2.6$.